# Angle between vectors when their dot product and norm of cross product are equal.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> I had a question in the final exam that asked what the angle between vectors **a** and **b** is if:
>   $$\vec a \cdot \vec b=|\vec a\times\vec b| $$

Any hints please.

Comment: If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are 3-dimensional vectors, then $\vec a\times\vec b$ is a 3-dimensional vector. $|\vec a\times\vec b|$ is the norm of a vector, and it is a number.  Then what does it mean by determinant of a number? Determinant of a $1\times 1$ matrix?

Comment: Oops. Actually, there should not be a determinant symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to show that $$\|u\times v\| = \|u\|\|v\| \sin(\theta),$$
where $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$.    This should lead you right to a solution.

Comment: Ok, so the angle is $\pi /2$

Comment: @Dostre, are you sure? The angle between $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ is $\pi/2$...

Comment: I do not think the cross product of two perpendicular vectors is $0$ ...